# Bind a property, inside DataTemplateItem in ListBox, to an outside object in MainPage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I got `ListBox` with `DataTemplate`, inside `DataTemplate` I got another `ListBox`, trying to bind it's `Visibility` to another object which is found in the `MainPage`

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="RegistersListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind registersList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="structures:Register">
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox x:Name="FieldsListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind fields_list}" Visibility="{x:Bind SomeVisibilityObjectIMain}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="structures:Field">
                            <Button Content="{x:Bind name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

C#:

```
public sealed partial class HWTab : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Register> registersList = new ObservableCollection<Register>();

    public var SomeVisibilityObjectIMain;

    public HWTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitData();
        this.DataContext = hwType;
    }

     ....
 }
```

I need to bind to "SomeVisibilityObjectIMain" somehow, I tried to bind with ElementName or even make object static, but could not succeed.
My bindable object is more complex than the example here but solve this will give me the way for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `{Binding}` instead of `x:Bind`. This way you could add a `x:Name="Page"` to your page and then use this name in the inner binding:

```
{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=MyProperty}
```

For `{Binding}` to work however, `MyProperty` must be actually a property. From your sample code (which uses `var` which is also invalid) it seems it is just a plain field, so you will need something like:

```
public string MyProperty {get;set;}
```

To also get `PropertyChanged` notifications, you will need to add a backing field and trigger `PropertyChanged` event.

However, overall a better solution would be to include all information a `DataTemplate` needs into the actual items which are bound to it. That means - you would create a custom view model type for the items, which would include the information that you need to control visibility.

Comment: Thanks! I tried before what you have suggested, including use of x:Name and Property and PropertyChanged. The problem was I did it as an outside class. Your solution to use inside the same page worked.